# Good vs fair? Which is better

Tags: differences

Which is better? Good or Fair?
Good: Method A
Fair: Method B
Which method is better? I'm confused

Comment: The idiom is from fair to good, so good is better than fair.  Dictionary for fair: _neither excellent nor poor; moderately or tolerably good:_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by mplungjan is correct, as it focuses on the definition of fair.

An alternative approach is to look at actual values used in surveys, or the recommendations from the survey design literature. Naturally, there is plenty of alternatives in designing survey scales. What many of them have in common however, is that fair is worse than good. For example, [this guide](https://explorable.com/survey-response-scales) shows:

- Three-point Scales:

> Good - Fair – Poor

- Seven-point Scales

> Exceptional – Excellent – Very Good – Good – Fair – Poor – Very Poor

For five point scales, [another used](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RABPCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=survey+design+five+point+scale+fair&source=bl&ots=gfN77NuIrU&sig=CZ7NjxbCaL_q0EpAZmUh_CrAopg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4pfCOx-fTAhXJL8AKHRfbBnYQ6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=survey%20design%20five%20point%20scale%20fair&f=false) is:

> Excellent – Very Good – Good – Fair – Poor

or [this](https://www.credit.com/credit-scores/what-is-a-good-credit-score/) one:

> Excellent – Good – Fair – Poor – Bad